# Android html POST not working, no errors given

Tags: java, php, android, html, post

I recently wrote some code in java that is supposed to send a string to a php script and it works perfectly fine. However it refuses to work when i use it in an android program. thought someone could help me find out what the problem is!

> ```
> public static String main(String x, String y){
>     if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
>     {
>         StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
>         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
> ```

```
    }else{

        try{

            String username = x;
            String password = y;

            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            // LÄSER FRÅN HEMSIDAN

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){

                result += line;
            }



            //AVSLUTA CONNECTION
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return result;

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    return null;

}
```

I did allow internet permission in the manifest by adding

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

but it simply gives me no result. At first i thought that maybe there was something missing in the php script but it works perfectly fine when being tested in eclipse, so there must be something wrong or missing from the android part, right?

Comment: can you add this `Log.d("HTTPSENDER",""+httpURLconnection.getResponseCode());` after you flush your data and see what you got? In some cases, this can solve your weird error too.

Comment: @user1506104 thanks, i'll give it a shot and see what happens! :)

Comment: did you get the response code? did it work?

Comment: @user1506104 no difference, still no errors or other messages

Comment: does it even execute your `else` block?

Comment: @user1506104 god i feel stupid... the code wasn't even running hahah... literally all that had to be done was for the code to be moved up within the if-statement hahah, thanks for the help bro :)

Comment: i added an answer so you can close this problem. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `else` block executes.

Answer (score 0):

That's a VERY bad practice - use Retrofit library for consuming REST apis instead. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

Comment: what makes it so bad? im asking because i want to learn, not to "protect" my code :)

Comment: there is nothing of 'protection' - you should write tests for your network code, or, in some case it may be unclear if some api not working or your code for consuming that api has some error. On the other hand, that library is already tested.